# Is there a way to concatenate characters in a string so that there are no spaces in between the letters?

Tags: python-3.x, concatenation

So this is it what it would look like

`string1 = "This is my string"`

output would be:

`string1 = "Thisismystring"`

Comment: `string1.replace(" ","")`

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> def foo(s: str):
...     return s.replace(' ', '')
...
>>> print(foo("This is my string"))
Thisismystring
```

```py
>>> def foo(s: str):
...     return ''.join(s.split(' '))
...
>>> print(foo("This is my string"))
Thisismystring
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
string1 = "This is my string" 
output = re.sub(r'\s', '', string1)
# or 
output= string1.replace(" ","")
print(output)
```